# In Android how to change the color of a particular letter/character which is being searched inside the List

Tags: android, search, android-listview, textview

I have a ListView containing certain items and I have placed a `EditText` above the list to provide the `Search` facility to the user, means, by typing inside the `EditText` and clicking any button etc., user can search whether certain item is present in the list or not.

Now what I want is that: if the letters / characters typed by the user are present inside any list item, then `those letters only` to be changed in RED or BLUE or any other color. For example I have a list of fruits and I am searching for `Apple`, so when I start typing app... le, then the color of only those characters which are typed by the user, `app` (in this case), should be changed to RED, BLUE or any other color if the item `Apple` is present in the list.

Can anyone tell whether this is possible to do in Android and if yes, then how to do so. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would like to know too +1.

Comment: me too ! what about using many `TextView`s. I don't think it's a good way ... ?!

Comment: use a SpannableStringBuilder for setting a ForegroundColorSpan

Comment: @swdeveloper editted the Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more simply way to do that is to register a TextChangedListener:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //retrieve the typed text lecter ad char array something like typedChar[]
        //Here parsing the List and modify the lecter
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Then we must reload the ListView, can use notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter (something must change to fire event)

```
myListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Finally in the adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapterOptimize extends ArrayAdapter<Contatto> {

      public CustomAdapterOptimize(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
             List<Contatto> objects) {
           super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           TextView tx = (TextView)convertView;
           SpannableString text = getItem(position);
           for(char:typedChar)
           if(tx.getText().contains(char)){
                // make "text" (characters pos-1 to pos) red  
                text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), tx.getText().indexOf(char) - 1, tx.getText().indexOf(char), 0);  
                textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
           }
      }
 }
```

Notice that this code must be adjusted for performance and logic but this can be a good startup.

Answer (score 3):

Consider My Short Hand Example to Do this:

```
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);  

    SpannableString spantext = new SpannableString("Nitesh Tiwari"); 

    spantext.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 6, 0);

    //This Will Print Nitesh In Blue Color

    spantext.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f), 7, 12, 0);

 // This will print "Tiwari" 1x  bigger than the remaining Figure

    textView.setText(spantext, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Hope this Could Help...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you may use something like this:

```
styledtext="This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```